# random forest with spark: get predicted values and R²

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, random-forest, prediction

I am using `MLlib` of `spark` to perform a `regression random forest`.

I am using the `python` code here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-ensembles.html#tab_python_1

It works but now I would like to get the `predicted values` as well as the `R` or `R²` of the prediction model.
How to get that?

Comment: you want the coefficient of determination of the prediction model?

Comment: coefficent of determination (`R²`) or coefficient of correlation (`R`), any of the two. In fact if I I get the list of the `predicted values` I can compute it with a formula

Comment: there is no direct way to get that from spark directly, you'll have compute it

Comment: ok. What about the `predicted values`? How to get them? I would like to store the `real`and `predicted values` in a csv file.

Comment: Map/reduce your training data RDD into an RDD of (real,predicted-value) then you can save the RDD. It's a very basic operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to save a `csv` file into `RDD` (spark data format):

```
# Imports
import csv
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import add, itemgetter
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest, RandomForestModel
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
import shutil
import numpy

def parse(row):
    """
    Parses a row and returns a named tuple.
    """
    row[0]  = str(row[0])
    row[1]  = float(row[1])
    row[2]  = float(row[2])
    row[3]  = float(row[3])
    row[4]  = float(row[4])
    return LabeledPoint(row[4], row[:4])    


def split(line):
    """
    Operator function for splitting a line with csv module
    """
    reader = csv.reader(StringIO(line), delimiter=';')
    return next(reader)

#save csv file on a spark cluster (RDD format)
data = sc.textFile("datafile").map(split).map(parse)
```

Here is how to perform the random forest algorithm and how to get the predicted values:

```
def random_forest_regression(data):
    """
    Run the random forest (regression) algorithm on the data to perform the prediction
    """
    # Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
    (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

    model = RandomForest.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, numTrees=100, featureSubsetStrategy="auto", impurity='variance', maxDepth=10, maxBins=32)
    #increase number of trees to have a better prediction

    # Evaluate model on TEST instances and compute test error
    predictions_test = model.predict(testData.map(lambda x: x.features))
    real_and_predicted_test = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions_test)

    #get the list of real and predicted values FOR ALL THE POINTS
    predictions = model.predict(data.map(lambda x: x.features))
    real_and_predicted = data.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
    real_and_predicted=real_and_predicted.collect()
    print("real and predicted values")
    for value in real_and_predicted:
        print(value)

    return model, real_and_predicted
```

To get the `correlation coefficient` (`R` value), I used `numpy`:

```
def compute_correlation_coefficient(real_and_predicted):
    """
    compute and display the correlation coefficient from a list of real and predicted values
    """
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    for tuple in real_and_predicted:
        list1.append(tuple[0])
        list2.append(tuple[1])
    print("correlation coefficient")
    print(numpy.corrcoef(list1, list2)[0, 1])
```

To get the `R²`, take the square value of the `correlation coefficient`.

Voilà !